# Can i use spring Remember-me to resume browser session after browser restart without the checkbox

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

For the following scenario where a user logs into my application and closes the browser and then restarts browser after some time and hit my application url then the user should get logged in automatically.

for this scenario my friend suggested to try to use spring Remember-me feature.
while i was trying to understand spring remember me concepts, in every example a check box is used.
Can i implement it without checkbox? 
Or this is a wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement is without a checkbox, but this is generally not a good idea if the site is publicly available on the internet. Imagine a user goes to the library and logs into your site, unless he remembers to click logout, the next user will automatically be logged in as the previous user (and most users just close the browser to log out).

When you post the login page, the remember-me checkbox is sent along as a normal post key-value pair. So if you always want remember-me, you can simply create a hidden field, with the value the checkbox would have when checked.

```
<input name="remember-me" type="hidden" value="on">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Klaus, the requirement is like that, its suppose to get logged in when browser restarts.

Comment: If you work in an enterprise setting there should be other ways of doing this, like Windows Authentication or some SSO solution. In most enterprise settings I work in remember-me is actually banned, because of security concerns!

Comment: yea but even gmail is having a feature to resume session on browser restart. I will definitely discuss this point with my co-workers.